# Suggestions for an efficient way to store raster files for lab use?

Tags: raster, spatial-database, database

I'm trying to create a repository for our raster files from various sources and Im exploring the possibilities on how to store them and deliver them in our local intranet. I have come across [rasdaman](http://www.rasdaman.com/) and seems like the tool for that kind of job.

Any suggestions on how to create a system like that would be really helpful

I'd prefer open source solutions over proprietary ones

Comment: The simplest solution is just to have a shared drive.  Do you have requirements beyond that?

Comment: It really depends on how your data come to you, what you need to do with them and how/if you need to ship them to others. There are so many options this question needs more details about your needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For spatial database with raster support you can use any of the following, depending on your requirements:

- [PostGIS Raster](http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/wiki/WKTRaster): From their website - "PostGIS Raster is an
  ongoing project aiming at developing raster support in PostGIS. It is
  a new project very different from the previous PGRaster project and
  also very different from  Oracle Spatial GeoRaster.

  The goal of PostGIS Raster is to implement the RASTER type as much as
  possible like the GEOMETRY type is implemented in PostGIS and to
  offer a single set of overlay SQL functions (like ST_Intersects)
  operating seamlessly on vector and raster coverages.

  PostGIS Raster will be integrated part of the future release of
  PostGIS 2.0 (spring 2012)!"

Although this is still under development, you can give it a try as this is open source, easy-to-use with GUI pgAdmin and offers lot of spatial functionalities.

- [RasterLite](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/): A very simple C library implementing an efficient
  storage solution for huge raster data sources based on SQLite +
  SpatiaLite Spatial DBMS. You can find the manual [here](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/rasterlite-docs/rasterlite-man.pdf).

This might be worth looking at as a light-weight alternative. This is also open source.

There may exist other options, too. However I personally feel, unless you are going to use any spatial functionalities for your raster data directly through build-in functions of the spatial database, it is always better to keep your raster data in file structure and save the path in your database. This will reduce your retrieval time, as well as improve your performance. Although there are limitations in this approach, you can easily deliver your data through LAN using a server side scripts.

Comment: A small point, but AFAIK there is not a GUI for loading rasters into PostGIS yet.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be to use [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html) to provide a [Web Coverage Service](http://mapserver.org/ogc/wcs_server.html) and not make the url publicly accessible.

I've had a good experience with PostGIS raster once I got over the initial hurdle of installing and loading data. I've used QGIS to access the rasters.

If you don't need to provide editing access to the rasters and a Web Map Service could suffice so the data can be overlaid with other data.

Answer (score 1):

PostGIS/Postgres and the Quantum GIS plugin DB Manager allows you to display raster images easily.